# FFMPEG : Cut specific parts of a video, and merge them in a single file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-editing

I would like to cut out specific parts of a mp4 video, and merge back those parts to create a single video file. This is to make an animated preview of the video.

More specifically : 
Cut out these parts of a video :

- Part 1 : start time of the cut = 20% of total time ; end time of the
  cut = 20% of total time + 3seconds,
- Part 2 : 40% of total time ; 40%nof total time + 3 seconds
- Part 3 : 60% of total time ; 60% of total time + 3 seconds
- Part 4 : 80% of total time ; 80% of total time + 3    seconds

(The videos are more than 3 minutes long, so there should not be any overlap in the parts)

Then merge those 4 parts in a new mp4 video file. How do you do that with FFMPEG ?

**Edit : so this is as far as I got for this question :**

I found answers to questions on "Superuser" and "Stackexchange" for these questions on FFMPEG:
-How to get video durations in seconds
-Cut part from video file with start/end positions
-Concatenate mp4 files

So : Get total time of video :

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration \
  -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal inputvideo.mp4
```

With the -sexagesimal I should get the right time format to use after.

Cut out part of video

```
ffmpeg -ss [start] -i in.mp4 -t [duration] -c copy /path/videopart[number].mp4
```

Right here I don't know :
How to do an operation on total time (20%, 40%... then 20% +3 seconds, 40% +3 seconds..)
How to properly implement it in the code line

Create a file videoparts.txt with the files names :

```
$ cat videoparts.txt
file '/path/videopart1.mp4'
file '/path/videopart2.mp4'
file '/path/videopart3.mp4'
file '/path/videopart4.mp4'
```

Then this should merge them in a single file :

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i videoparts.txt -c copy outputvideo.mp4
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

According to ffmpeg documentations [Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Timeunitsyntax) and [Time Duration](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Time-duration) the only way to specify 'seek time' is by giving the exact time.

You can write a shell script to extract total duration of video with ffprobe, calculate starting points and call ffmpeg with those starting points.